# Are HAIFA-construction based hash functions (e.g. Argon2) resistant to length-extension attacks?

Tags: argon2

Would a HAIFA-construction based hash function like Argon2 resistant to length-extension attacks?

I say that Argon2 is HAIFA-based because BLAKE is, and Argon2 is based on BLAKE.

Comment: I've unified the title and body on the answer's yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

The HAIFA construct as introduced in [A Framework for Iterative Hash Functions - HAIFA by Eli Biham and Orr Dunkelman](https://eprint.iacr.org/2007/278) is proposed with the explicit goal of eliminating various pitfalls of the classic Merkle-Damgaard construct.